# Macarons//egg whites with sugar are not sifting

Tags: baking

I am making macarons and I am mixing egg whites with the sugar and it is not creating soft peaks how do I fix it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your bowl and wisk are grease-free before adding the egg-white. And make sure that not even een little bit of the yoke gets in the egg whites.

The fat prevents the egg whites from stiffening when mixing.